# Como elegir variables con select?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Hola como podría con "Select" elegir una de las opciones de unas variables definidas y obtener el valor numérico e introducir el cambio en una función? desde ya muchísimas gracias!!!!!

```
    <select name="tipo" id="tipo" required>
    <option selected value="">Elige uno...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>


let volumen0 = 0;
let volumen1 = 1;
let volumen2 = 2;
let volumen3 = 3;
let volumen4 = 4;
let volumen5 = 5;


function voluen() {
    control(valorVolumen)
     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no puedes acceder al nombre de variable con otra variable, te recomiendo guardardo en un objeto `JSON`, y alli si puedes cambiarlo, no olvidar que el evento `onchange` será para capturar el valor nuevo del `select`

```js
var volumenes = {
  "volumen0" : 0,
  "volumen1" : 1,
  "volumen2" : 2,
  "volumen3" : 3,
  "volumen4" : 4
}


function voluen(e){
    var select = e.value;
    console.log({"valor de select": select});
    var variable = `volumen${select}`;
    console.log({"nombre variable": variable});
    var valorVolumen = volumenes[variable];
    console.log({"valor de la variable":valorVolumen});
    control(valorVolumen);
}

function control(valorVolumen){
  console.log(valorVolumen);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="voluen(this)" name="tipo" id="tipo" required>
    <option selected value="">Elige uno...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: no logro pasar ningun valor de var volumenes = {
  "volumen0" : 0,
  "volumen1" : 1,
  "volumen2" : 2,
  "volumen3" : 3,
  "volumen4" : 4
}